# Execute query as per condition using case statement in joining

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL SERVER 2008.  My query is giving me errors. I want to fetch data OR execute a query from the table `[DL_TRN]`.  If the record is not present in that table then I want to fetch details from another table `[D_Loan]`. I used the query :

```
DECLARE @DCount INTEGER;
SET @FCount=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [MsumCOOP].[dbo].[DL_TRN]  WHERE [M_CODE]=6162 AND ([LOAN_COMP]<>'Y' OR [LOAN_COMP] IS NULL));

SELECT m.[CODE],m.[NAME],d.[OP_AMT]
FROM [MsumCOOP].[dbo].[MEMBER] m
FULL OUTER JOIN ( SELECT CASE WHEN @FCount>0 THEN (SELECT [M_CODE],[OP_AMT] FROM [MsumCOOP].[dbo].[DL_TRN] WHERE [LOAN_COMP]<>'Y' ) 
                    ELSE (SELECT [M_CODE],'F' AS [OP_AMT] FROM [MsumCOOP].[dbo].[D_Loan] WHERE [LOAN_COMP]<>'Y')
                    END
                ) 
                d ON m.[CODE]=d.[M_CODE]
WHERE m.code=6162
```

Above query works fine if I just select a single field Like `[M_CODE]`  or count (in subquery in joining part) but not working for selecting multiple columns.
Please guide me to do this query.

Comment: `full join` with a `where` clause are cognitively dissonant.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a subquery that returns more than one column in the THEN clause of a CASE expression.

I know it's more code, but your code will actually perform *faster* if you write it like this:

```
IF @FCount>0
     SELECT ... {query that joins to DL_TRN}
ELSE
     SELECT ... {query that joins to D_LOAN}
END
```

Comment: Thanks but I have multiple tables .This solution is suitable if I have to work on single loan but I have to do for multiple loans and comparing conditions for each loan same as D_Loan.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many tables you have.  The point is your CASE hinges on the value of a variable, which is the same for all rows in your query.   Therefore you will get better performance if you use an IF and run a different query depending on the value of the variable.